# If/else statement is never reached / edittext null values

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make an `if/else` statement that if `s1` is `null`, it will show files from an SD card, but if `s1` is not `null`, it will show SD card file that contain user inputs. However, my code fails and never reaches the `if/else` statement:

```
EditText s1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search1);

    try 
    {
        for (File ff : dirs) 
        {
            //search.equals("")
            if (s1.getText().toString().equals(""))//if null
            {
                if (ff.isDirectory())
                    dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "Folder", ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                else 
                {
                    fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "File Size: " + ff.length(), ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ff.getName().contains(s1.toString()))//show file search
                {
                    if(ff.isDirectory())
                        dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"Folder",ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                    else
                    {
                        fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"File Size: "+ff.length(),ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                    }
                }
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, (CharSequence) s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: first of all `s1.getText().toString().equals("")` is not a null check..it is a empty check..please rephrase your question it is hard to understand. What is your problem..

Comment: the question is about how to check edittext input, if there is an input in edittext, it will go to the else statement, if no, it will go to the if statement, 
if i'm not using the if else, the Toast.makeText... that i comment, appear...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (s1.getText().toString()==null){
....
```

Comment: can that ever == null?  Won't it always be an empty string?

Comment: I agree with @Dr.Dredel - what reason would anyone have to override `toString` to return null??

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what your question really is but I suspect that this:

```
if (ff.getName().contains(s1.toString()))
```

Isn't what you think it is.  What are you expecting to get from s1.toString()?  It's not going to be the value of the EditText entry and it's not going to be the english looking ID that you gave it in the XML. It's going to be whatever internal java label is associated with this input, is that really what your file names are? if not then this match will always fail.

Comment: i wanna make some search files in sdcard that receive input from edittext (s1), that is why i use that code above...

i think the error it's not in that code, but in 

if (s1.getText().toString().equals(""))//if null 

(i think), but may be in my logic too...

Answer (score 0):

use this code..

```
if( edit_text.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
```